# Using selenium I want to scrape this text

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, web-scraping, webdriverwait

Hello guys I am trying to **scrape** from [this url](https://xangle.io/project/XTZ/full-disclosure) the following text using selenium:
[image]
But I get the error that it couldnot find any element by that class name.. This is my code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

driver = webdriver.Chrome(r'C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\Lib\site-packages\chromedriver_py\chromedriver_win32.exe')
driver.get('https://xangle.io/project/XTZ/full-disclosure')
driver.find_element_by_class_name('fv1').text
```

Comment: share html please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Induce `WebDriverWait`() and `visibility_of_element_located`() and following xpath.

```
driver.get("https://xangle.io/project/XTZ/full-disclosure")
print(WebDriverWait(driver,15).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH,"//div[text()='Token Name']/following-sibling::div[1]"))).text)
```

OR

```
print(WebDriverWait(driver,15).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH,"(//div[@class='token-profile-cont']//div[@class='fv1'])[1]"))).text)
```

Import following libraries.

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

Comment: it works but it gives me the wrong element.. it gives me "Company Profile" but i want to scrape the word "Tezos".. I encircled it in the screenshot.. could you help me.. and thank youuu for fixing the error

Comment: @SabbirTalukdar : I think it required log in to get the html?Could you please post the html of the element.so that i can give you exact solution.

Comment: i have shared the url, it would be a great help to you if you could visit that.. maybe this way you will see the whole picture

Comment: <div data-v-11ee3744 data-v-fbf8d28e class="fv1">Tezos</div>

Comment: this is the html tag

Comment: @SabbirTalukdar : The element on page `Token` its required login.However I can't reach that page without login.So you could take some time and post the html of the element it would be easy to give the answer?

Comment: Yes html tag of the element

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/211722/discussion-between-kunduk-and-sabbir-talukdar).

Comment: @SabbirTalukdar : Check the updated answer with xpath and let me know the status?

Comment: it worked thank you.. the second one you posted is more understandable to me, thank you

Answer (score 1):

The error is because there are multiple elements with the same class name.

Use XPATH to better traverse the page identify the element required.

```
WebDriverWait(driver,15).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH,"//div[contains(@class, 'token-name')]/div[2]")))

driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[contains(@class, 'token-name')]/div[2]").text
```

This will give you the Token name text content.

Comment: NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//div[contains(@class, 'token-name')]/div[2]"}
  (Session info: chrome=80.0.3987.163)

Comment: Try with webdriver wait.